# systemd-networkd: What is the configuration file precedence

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

I have a system I need to configure via `systemd-networkd`. For configuring the ethernet adapter `eth0` I created a file `/etc/systemd/network/eth.network` with the following contents:

```
[Match]
Name=eth*
KernelCommandLine=!nfsroot

[Network]
Address=10.0.1.100/24
Gateway=10.0.1.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

Unfortunately, after setting the logging output to verbose, I found that `systemd-networkd` actually reads its config from `/lib/systemd/network/80-wired.network` which configures DHCP for that adapter instead.

My question: Is it safe to delete/move that file? Why does it override my file? (I was under the impression, that `/etc` holds precedence over files that shipped with systemd.)

**EDIT:** I am using a modification of the poky reference distribution of the yocto project.

Comment: Please add to your question the distribution you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I added the distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files from the corresponding directories in /etc, /run, and /usr/lib are collected into a single list.

The precedence is *per-file* – if two files in /etc and /usr have **the same name**, then the file in /etc takes priority while the one in /usr is ignored. (The rest of /usr isn't ignored, only that one file is.) This applies to most systemd-related configuration.

Afterwards, in case of match-oriented files such as .network files, the entire list is **sorted by file name in ASCII order,** and the first matching file wins. It doesn't matter which directory the file came from – if it's at the top of the list it wins.

In ASCII, all numbers (0x30–0x39) will sort before any letters (0x40–0x7f). Meaning, `8*` goes before `e*`.

This is why the included file is named `80-something` – it leaves place for your custom files to be named `27-whatever` or `50-whatever`.

Comment: beware that only the first file with a matching `[Match]` is considered, the others are ignored.